# When someone adds a "language identifier" to a code block does the specified syntax highlighting show in the "suggested edits" "queue"?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, code-formatting, language-hints

When I edit someone's code block with a language identifier:

Example:

from:

````
```
def py
```
````

to:

````
```python
def py
```
````

Is that change reflected in the *Suggested edits* queue in the Inline or side-by-side modes?

Sure, it will be reflected in the side-by-side Markdown mode; but no one will have the time to check an edit in the Markdown content. Especially if the change is not shown in the Inline mode or side-by-side mode.

If someone doesn't see the change on the default side-by-side mode and **decides not** to view the Markdown, the edit has a chance to be rejected.

Example edit:

default side-by-side mode:
[image: side-by-side mode showing no difference]

side-by-side markdown mode:
[image: side-by-side markdown mode showing added language identifier]

---

Why bother: Language identifiers are a good feature of the Stack Exchange network, and it helps to understand complex code and for beginners - all in all if the OP likes it; if the OP doesn't like it, then the OP can reject it.

Comment: Syntax highlighting in review queues was disabled due to another bug and not enabled back up to this day. So yes, the chance of rejection when making these edits is high. Unfortunately, nothing we can do apart from pestering SE with "are we there yet?"

Comment: @OlegValter _pestering SE with "are we there yet?_ Can you post a link of the post case/issue or a _pastering_? and I would like the post of the bug.

Comment: @Gomesz785 it was a Simpsons reference :) As for the report and the "we disabled it everywhere for now", see [this MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408993/11407695) report and staff answer

Comment: @OlegValter the link you provided was a answer to a [question - "diff bug"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly). So that "diff bug" was fixed but syntax highlighting on the suggestion queue is disabled by SO because, if SO enable the syntax highlighting on the suggestion queue, the [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly) will start again? Am I correct?

Comment: Am I correct? did SO disabled syntax highlighting on the suggestion queue because of [this "diff bug"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly)?

Comment: Someone [already stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly/408993#comment853313_408993) of my current problem.

Comment: "but no one will have the time to check an edit in the Markdown content", then maybe they shouldn't be reviewing. If you don't have the time or are unwilling to spend the time to review the post properly and accurately, then you really shouldn't be reviewing the post. While we appreciate people spending time reviewing, it's more important that the reviews be done accurately than it is that the reviews be done quickly, or even at all.

Comment: @Gomesz785 you are correct in the interpretation, unfortunately - as a "hotfix" for another problem, language highlighting was disabled *completely* in review queues. Yeah, it's frustrating - used to be an active suggested edits reviewer on SO, but pretty much do none of this these days because the experience is far from perfect for every party involved.

Comment: The best thing you can do in the current situation is described by Luuklag - fix every other issue you see with the post, and describe that you added a language hint (don't say "improved highlighting" or "formatting" - most reviewers will be utterly confused because for them, code blocks will still be colourless)

Comment: [see staff response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly/408993#comment866334_408993) after a couple of reminders today - hopefully we will have it back in 6 to 8

Comment: " _If you don't have the time_ " @Makyen I am not a moderator blaming someone else for taking my valuable-cheesy-review-time by adding language identifiers. While I solely agrees to your idea, I won't be happy if that was a reply to my statement(which is not an even a statement; I used that for describe the possibility of rejection of such edits) in my question: _but no one will have the time to check an edit in the Markdown content_

Comment: @oleg your explanation is very simple - thanks for reminding the staff. btw what is "back _in 6 to 8_ "

Comment: @Gomesz785 ah, that's just an old [meme of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/786798) - means "will likely take an indefinite amount of time" :) Thank Luuklag, though - 'tis them who reminded Kyle about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is a good edit description. State in your edit description what was changed, so you could state: "Included language hint X for codeblock."

This will still leave some cases where people didn't read your edit description, and just disapproved because they saw no change, but that is then their fault.

At the same time make your edits as substantial as possible. In this case there are some words in caps, that could be turned to lowercase letters and highlighted by either bold or italics.

Comment: _just disapproved because they saw no change, but that is then their fault._ if this happens I can just keep adding the same language identifiers until some caring moderator reviews it?